# Numpys pinv seem slow?

Tags: python, numpy

I was playing around with numpys pinv, and it seems like it is quite slow. Compared to a homebrewed function:

```
def moore_penrose_inverse(data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    if data.shape[0] > data.shape[1]:
        results = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(data.T, data)) @ data.T
    elif data.shape[0] < data.shape[1]:
        results = data.T @ np.linalg.inv(np.dot(data, data.T))
    else:
        results = np.linalg.inv(data)
    return results
```

It seem to be way slower:

```
data = np.random.random((500,1000))

%timeit np.linalg.pinv(data)
335 ms ± 57.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit moore_penrose_inverse(data)
42.6 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

An they do return the same result:

```
np.allclose(np.linalg.pinv(data), moore_penrose_inverse(data))
True
np.allclose(np.linalg.pinv(data.T), moore_penrose_inverse(data.T))
True
```

For larger datasets, it also seemed that the pinv was around a factor 10 slower than the homebrewed.

I know numpy uses svd to calculate the pseudo inverse, but what are the benefits of this and is it worth compared to the loss of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the [Moore–Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), the code of Numpy of both [`inv`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L483-L553) and [`pinv`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1912-L2007), and profiling results, I can say that the performance gap comes from the computation of the **singular value decomposition which takes about 96% of the time** (at least on my machine).

I do not have a strong mathematical background on this, so please correct me if I am wrong: AFAIK, this SVD seems required for the pinv to provide *correct/numerically-stable* results when it is useful to compute this generalized inverse. AFAIK, the random matrix used in the example is not a pathological case where the generalized inverse is useful and a basic inverse can be used instead. I think it is related to the *rank of the input matrix* and random input matrices have the property of being *full-rank* while this method is useful when they are not.